Qt Creator remote compiling and debugging?
I am developing C++ software using QtCreator 6.02.
I have a puny desktop machine connected to a powerful server via a 1G wired LAN and I'd like to access the Qtcreator gui locally on the desktop while debugging and compiling the code remotely on my server. While I can run Qtcreator on my server using ssh X11, the GUI interface via X11 suffers from excessive latency. Running over VNC is better, but not convenient to debug/edit on all three of my 4K monitors connected to my HP 740 thinclient desktop. Yea, I could just upgrade to a 10Gb/s LAN system, but that runs some big bucks and I would have to crawl around in my attic to run the CAT 8 cables for this upgrade.
I tried to answer this via Google and Qt webpages but not getting a clear answer that I can understand.
Both my servers and HP thinclient desktop run Ubuntu 22.04.
Any suggestions most welcome.
Thanks in advance!
Tried google for answers. Could not find comprehensive Qt documentation, but it seems to indicate that remote debugging is possible. Most postings answers are very old circa to 2018

Have you tried doing a "remote desktop" to the server?  In the Windows world we do this to remote from home.  In the *nix world, we do this when the server is powerful and nobody is using the server.

Think a bit about the "3 x 4k monitors" bit and your required frame rate - then think again about your bandwidth requirements.
